# Android studio generate an APK error

Tags: android

Android studio generate an APK error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task    
':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForBaiduRelease'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:    
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
tv/danmaku/ijk/media/player/pragma/DebugLog.class
```

Comment: clean project and rebuild it

Comment: check your build.gradle. You might had define duplicate depenedency or your other library may be referening to some library which I already included in your project like support library.

Comment: clean project and rebuild and still problem there then add  defaultConfig { multiDexEnabled = true } in your app's gradle  and sync.

Comment: Show me your build.gradle file.